# How to use Hausdorff distance to compare geometries

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry

I implemented a Hausdorff distance algorithm for a collection of $[[x_1,y_2], [x_n,y_n]]$ vertices.  My question is, how do I interpret this distance?  Is there an additional step need to help determine polygon similarity?

```
from_array = np.array([[0,1], [2,4], [4,4], [0,1]])
to_array = np.array([[1,2], [3,5], [0,1], [1,2]])

def hausdorff(from_array, to_array):
    subs = from_array[:,None] - to_array
    sq_eucliean_dist = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',subs,subs)
    eucliean_dist = np.sqrt(sq_eucliean_dist)
    fhd = np.mean(np.min(eucliean_dist,axis=0))
    rhd = np.mean(np.min(eucliean_dist,axis=1))
    return max(fhd,rhd)
```

The distance is `1.06066017178`, but I'm struggling to find some meaning to this number.

Thank you

Comment: The explanation on Wikipedia is useful: *The Hausdorff distance is the longest distance you can be forced to travel by an adversary who chooses a point in one of the two sets, from where you then must travel to the other set. In other words, it is the greatest of all the distances from a point in one set to the closest point in the other set.*
More importantly, the "distance you must travel" is **determined by your choice of original metric** (which judging from your variable names is a Euclidean metric).

Comment: @parsiad so if i say the point or polygon must be .5 units away and it's 1.06 away, then it's not similar?

Comment: Your question is unclear.